# The inverse of $-1+\dfrac{\cos((\frac{1}{2}+m)w)}{\cos(w)}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

Is it possible to compute the inverse of the following function

$f(w)=-1+\dfrac{\cos((\frac{1}{2}+m)w)}{\cos(w)}$

when $0 \leq w \leq 2\pi$.

Comment: For a function to be invertible it must simultaneously be injective as well as surjective.Have you checked for this?

Comment: Surjectivity is not important since we can choose the domain.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily invertible on the interval $[0,2\pi]$ as shown in this example when $m=1$. You may try using other values of $m$ or other intervals at this [desmos.com link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4arynqvau1).

[image: graph of OP's function when m=1]